# Elementor Function is not working properly in Document.php

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am working on a site that suddenly has these error messages:

`[25-Aug-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: post in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php on line 250`

`[25-Aug-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Elementor\Core\Kits\Documents\Kit::$ in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php on line 250`

`[25-Aug-2022 16:23:38 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php on line 250`

`[25-Aug-2022 16:23:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/base/document.php on line 250`

The errors showed up whenever a customer tried to put a variable product into the shopping cart. On the front end it says:
[image: This is a screenshot of trying to add a variable product to the cart.]

This doesn't happen if the customer adds a non-variable product to the cart, so I am not sure what is happening or how to repair this. I have reached out to elementor with no response at this point after 24 hours.

The code referenced in the error log is:

```
    public function get_main_id() {
    if ( ! $this->main_id ) {
        $post_id = $this->post->ID;

        $parent_post_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

        if ( $parent_post_id ) {
            $post_id = $parent_post_id;
        }

        $this->main_id = $post_id;
    }

    return $this->main_id;
}
```

This occurred after the site was moved to a new hosting company, however, the site was working fine for the past three weeks, and the issue wasn't present.

Comment: To me, it looks like the cache issue, Please clear the cache from your cache plugin, from your server, and from CDN as well. then wait 5 mins and test the issues.

Comment: I did all that and the problem is still there. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Check your console logs, You must have any Js error due to conflicts or JS optimization. it doesn't look like a PHP error. and if it's a PHP issue then check you `debug.log` for logs

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out (With the help of Elementor Tier 2 support) that the hosting provider (Site Grounds) installs a plugin called "SiteGround Optimizer" that was causing this issue. There is a conflict between this plugin and Elementor in case anyone is having this issue.

EDITED: SiteGround was able to turn off the "Defer Render-blocking JavaScript" feature and the plugin worked with the rest of the site. If you are having a strange issue and you are on SiteGround, I highly recommend you turn this feature off to troubleshoot the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring on Kinsta too - so it's not just the SG plugin. It could still be optimization related - but I can't seem to find a resolution yet (even rolling back versions isn't helping me).

Answer (score 0):

that issue comes in new version of elementor, just rollback it previous version following this video https://youtu.be/3uwCRcQvIFw

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33188567)